# Is "from which he came" correct? Shouldn't it be "which he came from"?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> 1. The narrator speculates as to which asteroid from which the little prince came.
>    (*The little Prince*,  a novel originally written in French)

Do you find this grammar acceptable? I think it should be:

> The narrator speculates as to which asteroid the little prince came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't acceptable. The writer has tried too hard to avoid ending a sentence with a preposition and ended up with nonsense. (There are no chapter headings in the original story, so this comment must have been supplied by an editor/translator.)

They could have said *The narrator speculates from which planet the little prince came/has come*, but your version is fine if you correct the spelling mistakes.